# XML2PDF checkbox fields disaper after save in word

Tags: templates, ms-word, pdf-generation, ms-office

I have an old project, that has word templates, they are edited and used for generating PDF documents via the Altsoft Xml2PDF library.

I have an old word template and it works fine, but when somebody edits that template, for example: adds 1 letter and saves it on Word 2013 or Word 2016 and we try to generate a PDF, the checkbox fields disappear.

On a computer with Windows 7 and Word 2013 it works, but on other computers editing this template doesn't work.

Comment: Problem solved. I need to enable developer tab in ms word, and click "Properties" -> ok for each checkbox before each document save (I will try to automate this later).

Comment: ^ Please add an answer below, so you can mark the question as resolved using the tick icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I need to enable developer tab in ms word, and click "Properties" -> ok for each checkbox before each document save (I will try to automate this later)